# 3 layers(Projects): How can I throw an exception from first layer and catch it in the third

Tags: c#, exception

I have three layers:

1. ServiceHandlers ( which talks to the ax2012 and maps the data to entity)
2. Services ( Which calls the functions from serviceHandlers such as getOrder and returns it)
3. Winform(or could be whatever for someone to design the UI, uses the services logic to do so).

My problem is the exception handling in the ServiceHandlers. I implemented my own exception could `EntityNotFound` which i throw when the getEntity functions is called and doesnt find anything. What i do when i catch it is throw it again and catch it in Services.

Inside the catch block there i only use the statement throw; .. which i though would just throw it back again and then i was gonna catch in the catch statement in the winform layer. But what happens is that application stops in services layer and says "EntityNotFoundException" was unhandled which is okai but i want that to happen in the winform layer.

Hope this is understandable , so .. are there any suggestions ?

Comment: The way you're doing it should work.  Are you sure the call to your ServiceHandlers function is wrapped in a Try Catch?

Comment: Sample code???? Are you sure all layes are interacting synchronously? Why catch when you have to throw anyway unless you are logging or doing somoething with exception

Answer (score 1):

First off, Unless you are adding some value such as logging, or adding costume messages don't catch and rethrow exceptions. You can try ... catch the exception in the GUI layer to handle it there appropriately.

Second, a sample code would help to help you debugging the issue.

Comment: Catch and throw can often be necessary if the intermediate code needs cleanup or finalization in the case of a deeper exception somewhere along the way.

Comment: @J..., In general, I agree with you that is why I said catching and throwing *need to add value*. However, when it comes to specifics I've some reservation. First, You don't need a catch block to do finalization,try-finally will do the job. Second, if the intermediate code handled the exception( and performed exception related cleanup) it should create a new exception and pass the exception object as InnerException.